# int main(); C - java equivalent

Tags: java, c, program-entry-point, args

I'm an University student and new to java. Last year, second semester we did some programming in C. I test a lot of stuff before truly understanding it. In C I only need to start with int main() to start coding. Java is a bit more confusing. Why, do I "need" (I'm not sure if I have to start this way) to start with

```
public static void main (String[] args)
```

if I'm not going to use the argument in my program. This:

```
public static void main ()
```

gives me an error. I don't want to read in any arguments.

I hope you understand - English is not my Home Language.

Comment: Just use the first snippet and ignore the arguments. It doesn't hurt you in any way :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the answers. I would test Python or Lisp later maybe - we have to write our programs in Java - so I don't really have a choice :)

Comment: @Tauquir do NOT turn this into a flamefest !!! @ISJ ignore stuff like that please ... its just people angry at things they don't understand ;)

Comment: If Java is anything like C#, they also require you to stick Main inside a class definition, even if that's the only function in it.

Comment: C is probably more confusing here. It allows several definitions (and sometimes you even see non-standard ones like `void main(void)`), while Java requires that exact signature. And no reasonable IDE or compiler will give you any warnings for unused arguments in main(), so it really doesn't hurt anyone.

Comment: @Simeon; Well you may be right :).

Comment: Again, I don't know about Java, but in C# *and* in C, you are often allowed to make any non-standard entry point you want, using a compiler option to point to your new entry point.  It could be `void dance_in_the_rain(int countOfFishFallingFromTheSky)` as far as the compiler is concerned, as long as you tell it which one is right, and your C startup libraries can handle it.

Comment: @Merlyn In Java, you can have any number of entry points, each in a different class, but they each must be called main with the signature above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's just language definition.

The signature:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
```

Is the signature of the main method in Java, some languages have more than one main method signature.
You don't need to worry if you don't use the `args` array, it will just stay empty.

[This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_function) wiki page could clear things up a bit.

Answer (score 4):

C is quirky. If you declare a function as `int main()`, the arguments aren't checked. Properly, a C function that takes no arguments should be declared as `int foo(void)`, not `int foo()`. The C main function is really `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`, but since C doesn't care whether you put the args in the prototype or not, it will accept `int main()`. Java is more of a stickler (in more than one way) than C and requires you to actually type out the arguments to its functions, including `main`.

Comment: It used to be that you could declare an `int[] main` which you initialised to the machine code instructions you wanted it to run and the compiler didn't care. It does now. ;)

Comment: These comments by Merlyn are confused and off topic, as there is no c++ tag here. int foo(void) most certainly should *not* be avoided in C, regardless of who might have called it an abomination (and I doubt very much that Ritchie did).

Comment: @Merlyn, it is a well-known fact that it is the standard. Ritchie was probably referring to the decision to make it so in the language, not to the practice of actually using this "abomination", as it was already implemented. It just wasn't a good idea, so it was fixed in C++ despite the incompatibility. But for C it was apparently too late to change that. A code like `int f() {return 0;} int main() {return f(10);}` is perfectly valid in C, which makes it a bad idea to use `()` instead of `(void)`. In C++ it is the other way around.

Comment: @Sergey, Jim: Gross.  Okay, deleting my comments.  :)  Jim: I don't have a source for his comments, besides that comp.lang.c++ FAQ, so you may be right.

Comment: @PeterLawrey So the compiler was taking in ASM when you declared `int[] main` in this way?

Comment: @8protons it was taking numbers stored as bytes, which was treated as machine code when executing.

Answer (score 1):

In Java you have to start with a class and a full main method.  Given this is just one line of code amoungst what could be thousands or millions its really not a big issue.

You can have your IDE full in a class template so you don't have to type all these characters.

If you want to have a useful program with thwe minimum number of characters I suggest you try a scripting language like groovy or PHP, Python, Perl or bash.

EDIT: Java tends to be more verbose than other languages, however having a very terse language is not always a good thing either. One example is KDB

```
(!R)@&{&/x!/:2_!x}'!R
```

This lists all the prime numbers between 1 and R in one short line. ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't read in any arguments, then the args array will simply be empty. I don't think there's any technical reason why you can't leave out the argument in Java like you can in C, but the standard simply dictates that it has to be there.

Comment: There's certainly a technical reason: Java is strongly typed, and  so the entry point must have the right signature.

Comment: @Jim Balter Well sure, but methods can be overloaded in Java, and there's no reason why it couldn't allow `public static void main()` as an alternative signature and just ignore any arguments passed on the command line.

Comment: You've got it the wrong way around. Overloading allows multiple forms of message send, not receipt. The caller has arguments so it calls the version of main that takes arguments -- it isn't about to ignore them, and your providing another form of main won't cause it to do so.

Comment: you are completely free to have a `static int main()` method and a `static int main(int[] args)` method and a `static int main(String[] args)` method etc. However if you want to start your "class" as a program the java executeable is looking only for the `static int main(String[] args)` version. Suppose you give no args, how should it know which main to call?